# HAProxy dynamic server address based off of header value

Tags: networking, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

Hello I'm attempting to route traffic back to a users machine in order to run a site locally but picking up the headers/cookies/routing logic for other origins that HAProxy supplies. Thus far though I have not been able to figure out how to do this. The documentation says that use of environment variables are usable https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-server

> Any part of the address string may reference any number of
>             environment variables by preceding their name with a dollar
>             sign ('$') and optionally enclosing them with braces ('{}'),
>             similarly to what is done in Bourne shell.

but I would imagine there is a way of using an acl or sample fetch but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to. Below is an example of one thing that I've tried. I have done a proof of concept by removing ${hdr(originalIp)} and using my IP but I want it to dynamically use the requesters IP if the cookie is present

```
### Sample config
acl has_local_cookie cook_sub(local) -i true
use_backend local    if has_local_cookie
backend local
server local-origin ${hdr(originalIp)}:443 ssl verify none
```

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking. Can you provide an example of what you want to do, and a config you've tried?

Comment: updated to show an example config of what I've tried/ what I'm trying to do

Comment: Yeah... that doesn't work. You can't use a sample method inside an environment variable delimiter like that. You'd need to create one backend per `originalIP` and route to those backends using static `use_backend` lines or possibly even a [map](http://blog.haproxy.com/2015/01/26/web-application-name-to-backend-mapping-in-haproxy/)

Comment: Is there no way to dynamically tie the backends address to a header? was also looking at [source](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-source) which it looks like you can tie the ip to the value of a header.

Comment: Not that I know of. Source will define *from* what IP HAproxy will open it's connections to the backends, but not *to* what IP it will open them. Backends/servers don't usually change that often and should all be known. Why are you trying to do this in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to get HAProxy to use a developers local machine(the requester) as the server when a cookie is set on the request in order to debug their local solution while still having all the side effects of being proxied through this router. (the HAProxy instance sets cookies, headers, and could serve content from other servers based on request paths)

Comment: That's a slightly odd thing to do, but if there's not much turnover in your developers, it should be fairly easy to setup a backend each and route accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you're trying is that it you're treating the entire configuration as though it were constantly being parsed and interpreted at runtime, which of course is not the case.

Certain arguments to the various directives are static, others dynamic, but `server` declarations are most definitely static.  A server represents exactly one target address, not a different address per request.

You will need to configure a back-end for each developer, or you could put them all in one back-end, `backend local` with a single server declaration for each developer, `server dev-1 192.168.1.1:80 ...`, `server dev-2 ...`, etc.

Then `use_backend local if { cook_sub(local) -i true }`.

Then in the backend add a `use-server` to match the server names to the source IP `use-server dev-1 if { src 192.168.1.1 }` for each developer.

Note that `{ ... }` is an anonymous ACL, a much cleaner (imho) way of testing simple conditions, particularly when the conditions are only evaluated in one place in the config.  If you're testing the same condition in multiple places, named ACLs are better because they are only edited in one place, so you don't have to update them in multiple places like you would if you copy-pasted the same anonymous ACL around the config.